# C++20 Designated Initializers char[]

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer, c++20, designated-initializer

[C++20 introduces designated initialisers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers). I'm trying to initalise a character array inside a struct with the new syntax.

[Pretty simple problem, I think code may explain it best](https://godbolt.org/z/4SYz6_):

```
struct Test
{
    unsigned v;
    char b[12];
};

int main()
{
    char str[12] = "hello"; // Works.
    char strb[12]{"hello"}; // Works.
    //
    Test testa
    {
        .v = 100u,
        .b = "hello" //Doesn't work...
    };
    Test testb
    {
        .v = 100u,
        .b = { "hello" } //Doesn't work...
    };
    Test testc
    {
        .v{ 100u },
        .b{ "hello" } //Doesn't work...
    };
    Test testd
    {
        .v{ 100u },
        .b{ "hello" } //Doesn't work...
    };
    Test teste
    {
        .v = 100u,
        .b = {} //This works.
    };
    Test testf
    {
        .v = 100u,
        .b = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'} //This works.
    };
    return 0;
}
```

I find this behaviour bazzar, the `char str[12] = "hello";` line works just fine. But the same initaliation form doesn't work in designated initialiser lists.

**Question** : 
Why can't I initialize the char array with a string literal?

**Edit**

I was previously using GCC.
[This works with clang.](https://godbolt.org/z/Y8UHpT) Is there a workaround for GCC and, is clang or GCC correct?

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55227

Comment: ... so GCC rejects `Test testa { .v = 100u, .b = "hello" };` but in non-pedantic mode accepts `Test testa { .v = 100u, { .b = "hello" } };`, which is clearly nonsensical.

Comment: Interesting, sounds like compiler bug to me...
Thanks for the related link!

Answer (score 2):

Designated initializers are a minor variation of [aggregate initialization](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.aggr). The only use of the designator names are to decide which aggregate member to initialize from the given brace-or-equal initializer. The use of designated initialization changes nothing about the specific form of initialization and therefore, whether or not it is valid.

Given your `Test` object, `Test{100u, "hello"}` and `Test{.v = 100u, .b = "hello"}` are either both valid or both invalid. In both cases, `Test::b` is initialized in accord with [[dcl.init.aggr]4.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.aggr#4.2):

> Otherwise, the element is copy-initialized from the corresponding initializer-clause or is initialized with the brace-or-equal-initializer of the corresponding designated-initializer-clause.

Copy-initialization is the exact same process it would be if you simply initialized an array variable. Which is perfectly valid.

So your could should work. This is a compiler bug.

The GCC "workaround" is to wait for the bug to be fixed. Or go back to standard aggregate initialization until their compiler is fixed.

Comment: I hoped I was wrong and could just move forward with this. I've upvoted, but somebody might have a funny syntactic work around so I'll delay the selection of your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I would say you can't initialise it this way because they are not type compatible. Well, if seen on a strict level... or "pedantic" level ;)

A char array is not equal to a std::string even if they are closely related. To be type safe, the compiler disallows such assignments.
Even [char array and char* are not identical](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/whats-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c/), as Geeks for Geeks explain.

I cannot see anything nonsensical here... may be there is something I overlooked?

The spec you posted states in the "Notes" section at the bottom:

> In C, character array of size one less than the size of the string literal may be initialized from a string literal; the resulting array is not null-terminated. This is not allowed in C++.

I would argue that this explains it. But I agree, it is somewhat "hidden".

Comment: Thanks. But I am not talking about std::string, only char arrays.

I believe that quote only refers to initalising arrays with string literals that would drop their null character as a result of the initialisation.
So C++ doesn't allow initialisation of a char array when the null would be dropped.

Comment: I mentioned std:string because of the string literals you use for the initialisation and suspected a type mismatch because gcc could interpret char[] b and "hello" as being of the types <array> and <std:string> ans therefore prevents that initialisation... but this actually contradicts the C++20 specs you posted... I am clueless and actually had my post deleted. Idk why it pops up still. Nevertheless, thanks for your kind words and explanation.